# How to create node js https (Windows)

Tags: node.js, iis, https

I want to create API call by HTTPS and binding port with IIS (not sure to related?)
I've to try like:

```
var pk = fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem');
var pc = fs.readFileSync('cert.crt');
var opts = { key: pk, cert: pc };

var serv = https.createServer(opts, function(req, res) {
  console.log(req);
});
serv.listen(5000, "hostname.com", () => console.log("run server"));
```

or

```
var httpOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("privatekey.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("cert.crt")
};

https.createServer(httpOptions, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("run server");
}).listen(5000, "hostname.com");
```

but I have an error:

```
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available **hostname:port**
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
server.listen(5000, '127.0.0.1');
```

The server.listen() is an inbuilt application programming interface of class Socket within tls module which is used to start the server to listen the encrypted connection.

**host**: It’s the unspecified IPv4 address.